# How can I save a complex levelplot in r as svg or metafile with small size?

Tags: r, svg, metafile

I have a levelplot in made in R. I want it to save it as an SVG or Metafile. Since the levelplot has multiple layers and multiple rasters, the final svg or metafile (EMF) is huge (~ 300mb). Is there any way to save it as a small file without losing the details?

I have tried svglite and it is bringing the size into 150mb. I need a much lighter file.

Comment: Likely the reason that it is large is because there are lots of graphical elements being displayed. The intent of svg/emf is to support all of them, so if you have 10 elements versus 10M elements, it _must_ store all elements, so the file size is always going to scale with the size of the data. If you truly need a smaller file, then you can either (1) use `png(..)` or another raster format; or (2) sample your the data plotted.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans for the reply and explanation. Is there any way I can export the plot in high quality? It's for my journal publication and I am using Microsoft word for preparing the manuscript. I experimented with native png and tiff commands in r with different resolutions. I couldn't  get a desired output.

Comment: If there is tons of rasters and layers, then I would suggest to consider, if there is no way to aggregate the data in some way, like points in (predefined) polygons, or similar way. And then plot it as `.png`, usually 240 dpi is enough for any publisher. My usuall approach which merges few terra:plots(rasters) + couple of vector layers: `grDevices::png(file=paste0({{filename}}, ".png"), width=1600, height=1600, res=240) .... plot()...    grDevices::dev.off()`

Comment: I will try with png(). Thanks @GrzegorzSapijaszko for the suggestions.